# Rails - Ability to Enable/Disable Links on a View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a UserMailer View that has several link_to's like so:

```
<%= link_to('XXXXXXXX Link Title', item_url(@item, :only_path => false), :style => 'color:#5196E3;text-decoration:underline;') %>
```

The page has several different links. I'd like to know if there is a way to globally set in the view to enable or disable the links.

If enabled, the above would run like normal, if not the block above would just show the text (XXXXXXXX Link Title) and not be linked?

Any ideas other than wrapping every link_to inside a IF statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rails already provides a `link_to_if` helper...

So, define `@some_boolean` in the controller class, or if you want a true global, then set `$some_boolean` appropriately. Then use the `link_to_if` :

```
<%= link_to_if(@some_boolean, "Link Title", <url etc..>) %>
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if)

Comment: thanks I noticed link_to_if in the API, but IF link_to_if returns false, the output is still a URL right? I only want the output when false to be the LINK TITLE.

Comment: In case the first argument of `link_to_if` is false, then the output would be just the text of the link, not the URL. It does do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6):

you can create a helper method that takes your link parameters and returns the value that you want. which means you will only implement one IF statement.(which will be in the helper.)

great comment by Sean Hill: helpers should be in helper files :)

#### ApplicationHelper:

```
helper_method :conditional_link

  def conditional_link(string,url)
    if true_condition
      return link_to string, url
    else 
      return string
  end
```

#### in your view:

```
<%= conditional_link string, url %>
```

Comment: I add an example to my answer

Comment: Interesting, thanks ddayan.... so given the link example I have above, how would I update that to work with the helper?

Comment: I believe helpers belong in the helpers modules, not in the application controller.  Otherwise, this is a good solution.

Comment: lol you always comment a second before I commit my edit... i added the an example for the view

Answer (score 0):

if also want else part if condition not true then use this

```
<%= link_to_if( some_boolean, "Link Title", <url etc..>) { link_to "link title", <url etc..>} %>
```

remember if you wont use code block then text will appear and if u want to render link in other style in case of false then use code block.